# How to Share Data between Activity and Fragment via ViewModel Class in Android?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I wondered if it's possible to pass a String data which has declared in Activity class and pass the String data to ViewModel class then pass the data to Fragment class.

**ViewModel Class**

```java
class TimeTableViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<String> start_time_str = new MutableLiveData<>();

void send_StartTime(String start_Time){
    start_time_str.setValue(start_Time);
}

LiveData<String> get_StartTime(){
    return start_time_str;
}}
```

In ViewModel Class, I have `MutableLiveData<String> start_time_str` and it has been initialized as `new MutableLiveData<>();`

I would like to use `void send_StartTime(String start_Time)` function in Activity class to set value of argument `String start_Time` and call the `start_time_str` in Fragment class.

**Activity Class**

```java
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.add_schedule_save:
            String start_time_str = startTime.getText().toString();
            Intent intent_restart0 = new Intent(TimeTable_Add_New_Schedule.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent_restart0);
            TimeTableViewModel timeTableViewModel = new TimeTableViewModel();
            timeTableViewModel.send_StartTime(start_time_str);
            Toast.makeText(this,""+start_time_str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Fragment Class**

```java
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    TimeTableViewModel timeTableViewModel = new TimeTableViewModel();
    timeTableViewModel.get_StartTime().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String s) {
            mon_textView_11.setText(s);
        }
    });
}
```

In the Fragment class I call `get_StartTime()` function to get `start_time_str` and set the String value to my TextView. I think the `start_time_str` has been successfully set by function of `timeTableViewModel.send_StartTime(start_time_str);` in the Activity  Class because of Toast.maketext is worked like a charm. **However the TextView is not shown anything. I have tested Text Color is not white so that if the string value is correctly called, it should be appear on screen.** If you have any suggestions, I would love to hear your advice.
Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It really depends on how do you create your `ViewModel` instance. Now you are creating `ViewModel` by its constructor, but that is not a proper way. You should use `ViewModelProvider` or extension methods that were created by Google team.

If you go with `ViewModelProvider` you should do it like this:

```java
TimeTableViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(TimeTableViewModel.class);
```

It is important to pass the correct context to `ViewModelProvider` constructor call. If you are in fragment and you will just use `getContext()` instead of `getActivity()`, you will not get the same instance as it was created in Activity. You will create a new instance of `ViewModel`, that will be scoped only inside of fragment lifecycle. So it is important to use in both parts activity context to get the same instance.

Activity part:

```java
TimeTableViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(TimeTableViewModel.class);
```

Fragment part:

```java
TimeTableViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(TimeTableViewModel.class);
```

Is important that your fragment is located inside the same activity that is using this `ViewModel`.

But guys at Google has make it easier for us with some extension methods. But as far as I know, they are working only in Kotlin classes. So if you have Kotlin code, you can declare your `ViewModel` simply like this:

```kotlin
private val quizViewModel: TimeTableViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

For Fragment scoped `ViewModel` you need to write something like this:

```kotlin
private val quizViewModel: TimeTableViewModel by viewModels()
```

But you have to add Kotlin ktx dependency to your project `build.gradle` file. For example like this:

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0'
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer . I could not share data using ViewModel class because of the fragment is not inside of my activity class, so that I created new fragment then replace to the activity class. And It works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are using Navigation component, you can also scope your ViewModels by navigation graph like this: `val myViewModel: TimeTableViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.navigation_graph)`. Glad I could help. :)

Comment: what is the benefit of doing so?

Comment: Which part do you mean? Navigation scoped ViewModels?

Comment: With the latest directions from the Android team, we are usually using Single Activity in combination with Navigation component for building our apps. If this is a case, then we are actually creating a singleton that lives through the whole app if we use Activity ViewModel. To avoid that, we could break our app into different navigations and scope our logic components properly by navigation use case. For example, we don't need some OnboardingManager inside the Home screen of a logged-in user.

Comment: I know that already. My question ´was wether there is any difference between 

val myViewModel: TimeTableViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.navigation_graph)

and

myViewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(Application()).create(MyViewModel::class.java)

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Android Architecture and want to share `activityViewModel` in your `fragments`.

To get `viewModels` in `fragment` use below code:

```kotlin
private val fragmentViewModel: Fragment1ViewModel by viewModels()
private val activityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

and in `MainActivity` use below code:

```kotlin
private val activityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()
```

Comment: Is the first line of code misleading? You won't be able to access a ViewModel setup in the Activity using `private val fragmentViewModel: Fragment1ViewModel by viewModels()`

Comment: This is really helpful... I thought viewModels() were activity scoped by default! I wasted some time over this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using kotlin language
I'm used same as tutorial but not working
Here's example codes how to declare my ViewModel

add dependencies in build.gradle:

> implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1'

example of Activity class

```
class HomepageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityHomepageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        sharedViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        sharedViewModel.isMenuOpen.observe(this, {
            onMenuOpen(it)
        })
    }
```

example in Fragment class

> class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
> private lateinit var sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel
>
> ```
> override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
>     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
>
>     sharedViewModel = activity!!.run{
>         ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest fix to this problem, instead of giving the owner as "this" change it to getActivity().

```
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (mvm == null) {
                mvm = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(CounterFgViewModel.class);
            }
        }
```