# How to pass async data from host activity to child fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I've an host activity with 4 tabs, one fragment for each tab.

- In the host activity I collect the user's location through `FusedLocationProviderClient`.
- I want to pass that location to the child fragments.

It seems that I've to use a `ViewModel` like:

```kotlin
class LocationViewModel : ViewModel() {
    lateinit var location: Location
}
```

How can I inform the fragments when the `location` has been set by the host Activity?
Thanks.

### EDIT - Solution

Using `MutableLiveData` as suggested did the trick.

```
class LocationViewModel : ViewModel()
{
    private val mutableLiveLocation = MutableLiveData<Location>()
    val liveLocation: LiveData<Location> get() = mutableLiveLocation

    fun setLocation(location: Location)
    {
        mutableLiveLocation.value = location
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to setup viewModel sharing between activity and fragments. Check out the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60885459/how-to-share-data-between-activity-and-fragment-via-viewmodel-class-in-android

Comment: Either send it directly through the supportFragmentManager by finding the fragment tag or use subscription model like LiveData

Comment: Thank you guys, with your help I solved and I also shared the solution.